# how can i access the checked status of each checkbox in a datagridview control in c#?

Tags: c#

Please help me I want the user when he clicks on a check box something happens(i want the user to listen to a sound wave) but I don't know which event of the datagridview cell content click didn't work cause when i click any row the event occurs??

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the [`CellContentClick`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx) but you have to check if it's the right cell:

```
private void DataGridView_CellContentClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;

    var chkCell = grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    if (chkCell != null)
    {
        bool checked = (bool)chkCell.EditedFormattedValue;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell me how can i give the checkbox a default value of false at form load?

Comment: @SamuelKhoury: what is the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`? Don't you have one?

Comment: yes i have a binding source called singlebindingsource! i want the user to listen to a single when he checks the box and to stop the music when he unchecks it. also i want any other checkboxes to be disabled cause he cant listen to two songs at once!

Comment: @SamuelKhoury: then set the column which belongs to chis checkbox to `false` in the datasource.

Comment: which property of the checkbox column?

Comment: @SamuelKhoury: modify the datasource not the datagridview. You haven't mentioned which `DataSource` you assign to the `SingleBindingSource`. But you have to modify the records accordingly that the `IsListening` property(or whatever name it has) is set to `false`.

Comment: i have created a dataset called music albums that has a table called single!

Comment: @SamuelKhoury: i don't understand the problem, maybe you need to ask another question. I don't understand what _you_ don't understand ;)

Comment: I have a datagridview that contains a checkbox column! i want when the user checks the first checkbox to play the music and all other checkboxes to be disabled, then when he unchecks the checkbox the music stops! how can i implement this and on which event?